# Import certificate from one aws account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to import the certificate of domain from AWS certificate manager (ACM) on one account to another ... How can I do that ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in the end? Do you want to transfer ownership? Do you want to delegate subdomains to another account? ... ?

Comment: I'm trying to activate port 443 for https on the other account's load balancer . not transfer the ownership but just use the certificate to activate the https on the other account

Answer (score 1):

You can't export an ACM certificate from one AWS Region to another or from one AWS account to another. This is because the default AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS) key used to encrypt the private key of the certificate is unique for each AWS Region and AWS account. For more information, see ACM private key security.

You can create multiple ACM certificates with the same domain name across different AWS Regions and accounts. You can then use these certificates with services that run on AWS Certificate Manager.

useful link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-export-certificate/

Comment: yes i see that link but when i try to create another acm certificate from the other account , i got " pending validation" .. kinda stuck at pending

Comment: @AhmedNageh ACM uses DNS validation to verify ownership of the domain. If the domain is registered in the same account it can automatically create the DNS records for you. If the domain is registered in another account you need to manually create the DNS records in the Hosted zone in *that* account.

Comment: Yes, when you request a certificate, AWS ACM will provide you with a DNS record to insert into the zone for validation. Add that record to the zone in the other account. After a few minutes, the status should change from "Pending Validation" to "Issued". Be careful when copying the record from the console, as the value comes with domain information.